# No Reverse Match

Tags: python, regex, django

```
Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('Federal Airports Authority of Nigeria (FAAN)',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 

1 pattern(s) tried: 

['details/(?P<company_name>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/$']
```

This is my `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^details/(?P<company_name>[0-9A-Za-z]+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
    url(r'^full_list/$', views.full_list, name='full_list' ),
]
```

This is the `models.py`

```
class CompanyDetail(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    company_logo = models.FileField(default='')
    company_info = models.TextField()
    company_address = models.TextField()
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is my `views.py`

```
def details(request, company_name):
    company = CompanyDetail.objects.get(name=company_name)
    return render(request, 'company_profiles/details.html',
    {'company':company} )

def full_list(request):
    lists = CompanyDetail.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'company_profiles/full_list.html', 
    {'lists':lists})
```

This is the template :

```
{% extends 'company_profiles/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% for company in lists %}
    <p>
    <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
     <a href="{% url 'company_profiles:details' company.name %}" class="alert-link">{{ company }}</a>
    </div>
    </p>


{% empty %}
    <p>No companies found</p>

{% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I only get no reverse match when there are spaces in the company name.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your regex

```
(?P<company_name>[0-9A-Za-z]+)
```

doesn't allow for spaces in the company name.  Django correctly tells you there is no reverse match.

Pick one of the options below:

- Change the name validation code to disallow spaces (and migrate existing rows), or
- Change the regex in `urls.py` to allow spaces

I recommend the second option.

Comment: This worked:     url(r'^details/(?P<company_name>[A-Za-z0-9_ +()]+)/$', views.details, name='details'),

Answer (score -1):

You should try this in urls.py for match company name

```
(?P<company_name>[\w-]+)
```

and also one thing why you are not using Company ID as a parameter? like below:

**in urls.py**

```
(?P<company_id>[0-9]+)/
```

**in templates**

```
<a href="{% url 'company_profiles:details' company.pk %}" 
class="alert-link">{{ company }}</a>
```

Comment: I guess he want name in url not id. Personal choices right.

Comment: but title is not good way. otherwise he should use slug field.

Comment: Could you please explain a little?

Comment: https://seo-hacker.com/url-seo-tutorial/ read full article about slug why slug is good in URL